# Return data type of expression in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get the data type of an expression in Oracle?

For example, in Teradata I can write

```
SELECT TYPE(4 + 4);
```

and get Integer. But the same doesn't work in Oracle

```
SELECT TYPE(4 + 4)
  FROM dual;
```

Returns an error. I know I can look at the table description, but this way would come in handy if it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no `TYPE()` function in Oracle.

One approach is to use the `DUMP` function, as in:

```
select dump(4+4) from dual;

DUMP(4+4)         
------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,9
```

This shows the data type as 2. Then you need to check the documentation to see what that means. For example:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG

Here you can see that Code = 2 corresponds to data type `NUMBER`.

Still a pain in the butt, but at least there is a way.

Alas, Oracle doesn't seem to offer a table (code, data_type) in the db, but you can build one yourself - then you can combine it with `DUMP` so you can always get the data type in a single `SELECT`.

Comment: Hmmm... actually that'll be just fine. I can easily write my own function which converts that output to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @mathguy Probably much better approach is to use DBMS_SQL and parse and descirbe statement (like TOAD) to get full info. Anyway Oracle has built-in mechanism to translate internal type code to name: `BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_TF.COLUMN_TYPE_NAME(dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(TYPE=>2)));
END;`

Comment: @lad2025 - What Oracle version do you need for that? I am running 12.1 and Oracle doesn't like `DBMS_TF.COLUMN_TYPE_NAME`.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry I ought to mention that, I've checked it with [LiveOracle 18c](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html). I believe it should be available with 12.2 (but undocumented)

Comment: Package `dbms_tf` exists in 12.2 but it has no `column_type_name` function. Interesting though.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to materialize it:

```
CREATE TABLE test_temp AS
SELECT 4 + 4 AS result
FROM dual
WHERE 1=2;

SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE table_name = 'TEST_TEMP';

DROP TABLE test_temp PURGE;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22898948ba50352c21d4bf469a27086b)**

---

If you have `TOAD for Oracle` you could use:

```
Editor -> Describe(Parse) Select Query
```

or highlight query and press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

From [Toad for Oracle 12.11 - Getting Started Guide](https://support.quest.com/technical-documents/toad-for-oracle/12.11/getting-started-guide/28):

> Use the **Describe (Parse) Select Query** function to see what columns would be returned if the query were executed. This is useful for tuning a LONG query before it is executed.

Comment: Nice... you dropped the table :D

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Actually, you can materialize it in a view that returns no rows.  That is a trick I've used in the past in other databases . . . and maybe even in Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, thanks. Of course we need only metadata so we could skip any rows.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to @Iad2025's response, that I think is good, some drivers offer you metadata of the "resultset" of a query.

This metadata is theoretically available in any JDBC driver, so you can retrieve it right after the "prepare statement" operation without actually executing the query.

However -- and this is a big one -- not all drivers actually implement this functionality. You would need to test your case and see.